# I want to show Navigation like image

Tags: moodle

I have a problem in Moodle: I cannot show and hide navigation.

I go to `plugin` => `block` => `manage blocks`, but this function cannot be useful:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can hide or enable the Navigation block from Site Administration->Plugins->Blocks->Manage blocks. Which version of Moodle are you using?